# Gitlab CI YML Mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I want to use Gitlab CI to deploy my static website to ftp server on commit in master. I had no experience in DevOps and try to do this by tutorials on Internet.
I made this .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - master
        deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -u ftp-login,ftp-pass ftp.server \
           -e "mirror -e -R -x .git -x excl.txt -x exclude-1 -x exclude-2 -x README.md -p ./ mysite/www/ ; quit"
```

But gitlab shows me error with this yml file. It says that Mapping values are not allowed in this context. Can you help me with this file? Thanks!

Comment: Indention is messed up, plus there's an extra `deploy:` keyword there.

Answer (score 8):

Had same error message

```
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context gitlabci
```

The problem in my case was `:`

Check out docs:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#script

Sometimes, script commands must be wrapped in single or double quotes. For example, commands that contain a colon (:) must be wrapped in single quotes ('). The YAML parser needs to interpret the text as a string rather than a “key: value” pair.

For example, this script uses a colon:

```
job:
  script:
    - curl --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://gitlab/api/v4/projects"
```

To be considered valid YAML, you must wrap the entire command in single quotes. If the command already uses single quotes, you should change them to double quotes (") if possible:

```
job:
  script:
    - 'curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" "https://gitlab/api/v4/projects"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After single and double quotes, you can use escaped double quotes, e.g.: `'python argparser.py --kwargs="{\"assignee_id\": ${GITLAB_USER_ID}}"'`

Comment: Gitlab doc location has changed. Find the updated doc regarding special script characters here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script